# How can I display a tooltip on an HTML "option" tag?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, tooltip

Either using plain HTML or jQuery assisted JavaScript, how do you display tooltips on individual `<option>` elements to aid the decision process (*there is not enough room for a different kind of control and some help will be needed*).

Can this be done though a plug-in or similar?

I have tried a few tooltip plugins for jQuery with no success (including the one called Tooltip).

This solution should:

- work in IE, WebKit as well as Gecko;
- utilizing standard `<select>` wrapped `<option>` elements.

So if the solution wants to use other tags it should convert those elements into what it needs dynamically (and not expect the initial mark-up to be any different).

---

The code for this can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vaRAA/), it is under the SafeSurf section, where I want to display some help on rollover of the options as to the meaning of the choices. At present it can only be displayed "after the fact" and some upfront help for the user would be beneficial.

**Appreciate that this is not easy and that something will probably need to be created - so the bounty will be awarded to the most complete solution or the specific hook that lands me closest to a solution I can create.**

Comment: apart from the question, i don't understand all these downvotes to the answers below...

Comment: The down votes were for answers I did not find useful. So being told it is not possible, answering with a solution that only worked in one browser or using a GUI toolkit that jumped around the page (not operating like a select box) did not help. Whereas demonstrating the event model in something that be tested on different browsers did.

Comment: From the FAQ of this site: `Be nice`. Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat you. `Be honest`. If you see misinformation, _vote it down_. From me: I don't see any misinformation on these answers, if you don't find them useful as long as they are not erroneus just put a comment why they are not useful.

Comment: Humble apologies, took the tooltip at face value on a personal level. If I could take them back now I would (for each one) - if a moderator can/will do this then yes please.

Comment: You're basically looking for a dropdown plugin which copies the `title` attribute of the option element into the generated `<li>` or `<a>` element. No one comes to mind, so you'd like to modify an existing one or to reinvent one. Sorry for not posting as an answer since that's basically already given by balupton. Just wanted to give a thought :)

Comment: That's probably correct. Unless anyone comes up with anything better in the next 4 days. Once done I'll submit the plug-in here.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

It seems in the 2 years since this was asked, the other browsers have caught up (at least on Windows... not sure about others). You can set a "title" attribute on the option tag:

`<option value="" title="Tooltip">Some option</option>`

This worked in Chrome 20, IE 9 (and its 8 & 7 modes), Firefox 3.6, RockMelt 16 (Chromium based) all on Windows 7

Comment: In Opera, it only seems to work in non-dropdown select boxes.

Comment: Working on Safari Version 10.0.2 (12602.3.12.0.1)

Comment: DOESNT WORK for Firefox v52x in a Linux box

Comment: Testing this with bootstrap in Chrome 119, it oddly shows the `title` value in the dropdown.

Answer (score 11):

If increasing the number of visible options is available, the following might work for you:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Select Option Tooltip Test</title>
        <script>
            function showIETooltip(e){
                if(!e){var e = window.event;}
                var obj = e.srcElement;
                var objHeight = obj.offsetHeight;
                var optionCount = obj.options.length;
                var eX = e.offsetX;
                var eY = e.offsetY;

                //vertical position within select will roughly give the moused over option...
                var hoverOptionIndex = Math.floor(eY / (objHeight / optionCount));

                var tooltip = document.getElementById('dvDiv');
                tooltip.innerHTML = obj.options[hoverOptionIndex].title;

                mouseX=e.pageX?e.pageX:e.clientX;
                mouseY=e.pageY?e.pageY:e.clientY;

                tooltip.style.left=mouseX+10;
                tooltip.style.top=mouseY;

                tooltip.style.display = 'block';

                var frm = document.getElementById("frm");
                frm.style.left = tooltip.style.left;
                frm.style.top = tooltip.style.top;
                frm.style.height = tooltip.offsetHeight;
                frm.style.width = tooltip.offsetWidth;
                frm.style.display = "block";
            }
            function hideIETooltip(e){
                var tooltip = document.getElementById('dvDiv');
                var iFrm = document.getElementById('frm');
                tooltip.innerHTML = '';
                tooltip.style.display = 'none';
                iFrm.style.display = 'none';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select onmousemove="showIETooltip();" onmouseout="hideIETooltip();" size="10">
            <option title="Option #1" value="1">Option #1</option>
            <option title="Option #2" value="2">Option #2</option>
            <option title="Option #3" value="3">Option #3</option>
            <option title="Option #4" value="4">Option #4</option>
            <option title="Option #5" value="5">Option #5</option>
            <option title="Option #6" value="6">Option #6</option>
            <option title="Option #7" value="7">Option #7</option>
            <option title="Option #8" value="8">Option #8</option>
            <option title="Option #9" value="9">Option #9</option>
            <option title="Option #10" value="10">Option #10</option>
        </select>
        <div id="dvDiv" style="display:none;position:absolute;padding:1px;border:1px solid #333333;;background-color:#fffedf;font-size:smaller;z-index:999;"></div>
        <iframe id="frm" style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:998"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not viable but it does answer the question directly. Hat off!

Comment: it's not working when I remove the size="10" from select tag! http://jsfiddle.net/7xbwemzL/

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: obj.options is undefined

Answer (score 4):

At least on firefox, you can set a "title" attribute on the option tag:

`<option value="" title="Tooltip">Some option</option>`

Comment: Agreed - I'm already using title="" and unfortunately WebKit it falls by the wayside.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried doing this on Chrome:

```
var $sel = $('#sel'); $sel.find('option').hover(function(){$sel.attr('title',$(this).attr('title'));console.log($(this).attr('title'))}, function(){$sel.attr('title','');});
```

However, the hover enter never fires... So you wouldn't be able to do this at all using the standard select. You could achieve this though through some non standard ways:

- You could fake a select box by using radio boxes that look like dropdowns. So for example, have a radio box absolute positioned and opacity set to 0 placed over the styled box that is pretending to be the option.
- Or you could use pure javascript and have a series of boxes and adding javascript onclick events to recreate the dropbox yourself - so you will update a hidden value with whichever box was clicked using javascript.
- Or use one of the non standard libraries already out there. (If there are any?)

Comment: I've updated my post to go into the details of my proposed alternatives further. Should make for a good head start :-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this would be possible to do across all browsers.

W3Schools reports that the [option events](http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) exist in all browsers, but after setting up [this test demo](http://jsbin.com/anime3/). I can only get it to work for Firefox (not Chrome or IE), I haven't tested it on other browsers.

Firefox also allows mouseenter and mouseleave but this is not reported on the w3schools page.

---

Update: Honestly, from looking at the example code you provided, I wouldn't even use a select box. I think it would look nicer with a [slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps). I've [updated your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vaRAA/1/). I had to make a few minor changes to your ratings object (adding a level number) and the safesurf tab. But I left pretty much everything else intact.

Comment: I've updated my answer... it's a personal opinion, but maybe a better option for you.

Comment: Aha, yes a slider *seems* like a much better option for this. The question still stands but will probably use on in the final code.

Answer (score 3):

Why use a dropdown at all? The only way the user will see your explanatory text is by blindly hovering over one of the options.

I think it would be preferable to use a radio button group, and next to each item, put a tooltip icon indicating additional information, as well as displaying it after selection (like you currently have it).

I realize this doesn't exactly solve your problem, but I don't see the point in struggling with an html element that's notorious for its inflexibility when you could just use one that's better suited in the first place.

Comment: After 11 years, your idea still makes sense. But I'm setting up a Dat GUI, which doesn't have radio buttons. You can fake checkbox as a radio button, but I find it too hackish. So displaying a tooltip over select options is still the better way to go IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that you can achieve this functionality with standard `<select>` element.

What i would suggest is to use such way.

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/

The basic version of it won't take too much space and you can easily bind `mouseover` events to sub items to show a nice tooltip.

Hope this helps, Sinan.

Comment: The flat drop downs here cause browser windows to jump around like a mad man - also by not using the &lt;select&gt; tags it goes odd on mobile browsers.

Comment: that is just the idea what i suggested is not taking the ready solution on that link. An `ul` unordered list is supported on any browser, and the rest is just showing and hiding `li` items. I still believe this should be the way to go.