# How can I add a Title attribute to a dynamically populated <SELECT>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function dynAddOption(list, elementToBeAdded){
    if( list.length > 0) {
        for(var index = 0;  index < list.length; index ++){
            elementToBeAdded.options[index + 1]  = new Option(list[index].description, list[index].id);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I give each of the `<option>`s a tooltip?

Comment: I doubt if it will be cross-browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display a tooltip on an HTML "option" tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249591/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-on-an-html-option-tag)

Comment: @Bergi that question does not show how to programmatically add the `title` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249591/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-on-an-html-option-tag) it is possible, you just need to add a `title` attribute. In which case this should work:

```
function dynAddOption(list, elementToBeAdded){
    if (list.length > 0) {
        for(var index = 0; index < list.length; index ++) {
            var opt = new Option(list[index].description, list[index].id);
            opt.title = 'Foo'; // < this is the tooltip
            elementToBeAdded.options[index + 1] = opt;
        }
    }
}
```