# How can i add a tool tip to show the selected value in dropdown using bootstrap or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i add a tool tip to show the selected value in dropdown using bootstrap or jquery

```
<select>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips I believe that will work with select.options

Comment: It wont show the selected value in dropdown

Comment: Can you explain i detail please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249591/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-on-an-html-option-tag

Answer (score 0):

Add bootstrap [tooltip.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/tooltip.js) plugin and try below.

```
<select id="select">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>



$("#select").change(function(){
       $(this).attr("data-original-title", $(this).val());
       $(this).tooltip();
   });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xphp2xys/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need tooltip.js in your bootstrap build. Something like this might work.

```
<!-- markup -->
<select id="mydropdown">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

// JS
$("#mydropdown").change(function() {
    $(this).tooltip({
        title: $("#mydropdown option:selected").val()
    });
});
```