# How to add tooltip on each select option with bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am trying to add tooltip to each select option with bootstrap-select. While I inspecting it seems the select-js converting the select tag to ul. I have no idea this is the reason for my code is not working.

**html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label  for="email">Network : </label>
    <select  id="basic" class="selectpicker form-control" >
        <option value="0" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Finding your IMEI number">One</option>
        <option value="1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Next title" >Two</option>
        <option value="2" >Three</option>
        <option  value="3">Four</option>
        <option value="4">Five</option>
        <option value="5">Six</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**js**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var mySelect = $('#first-disabled2');

  $('#special').on('click', function () {
    mySelect.find('option:selected').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    mySelect.selectpicker('refresh');
  });

  var $basic2 = $('#basic2').selectpicker({
    liveSearch: true,
    maxOptions: 1
  });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 2 tooltips on html select's option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964891/bootstrap-2-tooltips-on-html-selects-option)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

##### Update 2021-06-25

It seems that for versions `1.13.x` and higher, the solution is to use:

`$('#select').data('selectpicker').selectpicker.main.elements` - which returns an array of `li` elements that you can use.

as described on the Github issues page of this plugin:

https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2561#issuecomment-787112874

---

`Bootstrap-select` creates new DOM elements (an `<ul>` with `<li>`s) in order to render the dropdown items.

The problem with your code is that the tooltips are attached to the original `option` elements.
But they have to be attached to the newly created elements.

However, we should attach them only after the `Bootstrap-select` plugin is initialized, so we can take advantage of the `loaded.bs.select` event (From the plugin docs: "*This event fires after the select has been initialized.*" - https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/#events).

Also, the plugin is not copying all the attributes from the `option` elements, so the list items will not have set the `title` attribute. We have to copy this attribute manually.

In order to find the list items created by the plugin, we can take advantage of the `.data('selectpicker')` attribute, which is appended to our original `select` element, and contains all the data that we need.
The list items are found in `.data('selectpicker').$lis` object.

Please check the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#basic').selectpicker({
     liveSearch: true
     // other options...
    }).on('loaded.bs.select', function(e){

      // save the element
      var $el = $(this);

      // the list items with the options
      var $lis = $el.data('selectpicker').$lis;

      $lis.each(function(i) {
        
          // get the title from the option
          var tooltip_title = $el.find('option').eq(i).attr('title');

          $(this).tooltip({
             'title': tooltip_title,
             'placement': 'top'
          });
  
       });

    });

});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/61kbe55z/.

Comment: Does not work in latest boostrap-select 1.13.14. The $lis variable of your code becomes undefined as they might have changed the variable structure/names. Tried to use $element[0] instead but that also did not help. Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saphemlock/txbvjmy4/19/). Looking for other alternatives.

Comment: found something with: `var $lis = $el.data('selectpicker').selectpicker.main.elements;`: https://jsfiddle.net/tbdxs5jp/7/

Comment: It works only when we have static title in options. If we are loading dynamic values into title . it does not shows tooltip. Has anyone checked with dynamic values?

Comment: @amar ghodke, what version do you use? can you please provide a fiddle with a minimal reproducible example so that I can inspect the problem in detail?

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.js .  fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/xvhq7j4m  Please let me know if its accessible to you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xvhq7j4m/6/ one more updated link @andreivictor

Comment: In the initial solution, the tooltips are attached in the `loaded.bs.select` event, but when this event is triggered, the ajax request is not completed. Since you are already using `.selectpicker('refresh')`, we can take advantage of `refreshed.bs.select` event and attach the tooltips in the callback of this event - fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wskm4edz/

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code, no need to handle in js.
Use title attr on option to specify the text to be displayed on button after selected, if not specified will face issues with tooltip on button.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label  for="email">Network : </label>
    <select  id="basic" class="selectpicker form-control" >
        <option value="0" title="one"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Finding your IMEI number">One</span></option>
        <option value="1" title="two"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Next title" >Two</span></option>
        <option value="2" >Three</option>
        <option  value="3">Four</option>
        <option value="4">Five</option>
        <option value="5">Six</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This code does not work in latest bootstrap-select 1.13.14. You may just replace your code in my fiddle mentioned in above answer. Strange!

Answer (score -2):

Check this working code here please take this as reference.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:80px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select name="opts" id="opts" class="form-control" multiple>
                        <option value="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 1">option 1</option>
                        <option value="2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 2">option 2</option>
                        <option value="3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 3">option 3</option>
                        <option value="4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 4">option 4</option>
                        <option value="5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 5">option 5</option>
                        <option value="6" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 6">option 6</option>
                    </select>
                    <div id="tooltip_container"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Only works for multiple select, not regular select.