# bootstrap-select tooltip in ajax setup shows only once

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have achieved adding & showing bootstrap tooltip on bootstrap select options using this source. [How to add tooltip on each select option with bootstrap-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669038/how-to-add-tooltip-on-each-select-option-with-bootstrap-select)

on static setup all working fine

The problem is with ajax setup. I  am able to get tooltip on first dropdown select.
When I try to select for same select dropdown for second time it does not show tooltip and same behavior with next select dropdown

eg. 'imudetails' select and onwards.

I have 5 select dropdown select which gets activate one after another using on change methods given below and I have tired adding  `$('.selectpickerdrop').selectpicker('refresh');`
at bottom of ajax success function but the behavior is still same. It only works for once.

I am using `Bootstrap-select v-1.13.18` with `bootstrap tooltip, bootstrap version - 4.x` and `popper.js-1.16.1` `jquery 3.x` and `jquery-ui 1.12.1`. Ready to connect if additional information required.

html

```
<select class="selectpickerdrop form-control" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" data-size="5" id="marketdetails" name="marketdetails"></select>
```

select on change functions

```
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$("#marketdetails").on('change', function () {
    parentAttributeValue = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
    if (parentAttributeValue != 0) {
        portfolioTypeId = 'NT_ID_007';
        control = $('#mudetails');
        control.html('');
        GetHierarchyDetails(portfolioTypeId, parentAttributeValue, control);
        if (RecordCount > 0) {
            $("#mudetails").val("0");
            $('#mudetails').attr('disabled', false);
            $("#budetails").val("0");
            $('#budetails').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#sbudetails").val("0");
            $('#sbudetails').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#sbu2details").val("0");
            $('#sbu2details').attr('disabled', true);
            $('.selectpickerdrop').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    }
    else {
        $("#mudetails").val("0");
        $('#mudetails').attr('disabled', true);
        $("#budetails").val("0");
        $('#budetails').attr('disabled', true);
        $("#sbudetails").val("0");
        $('#sbudetails').attr('disabled', true);
        $("#sbu2details").val("0");
        $('#sbu2details').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.selectpickerdrop').selectpicker('refresh');
    }
    $('.selectpickerdrop').selectpicker('refresh');
});


$("#mudetails").on('change', function () {
    parentAttributeValue = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
    if (parentAttributeValue != 0) {
        portfolioTypeId = 'NT_ID_001';
        control = $('#budetails');
        control.html('');
        GetHierarchyDetails(portfolioTypeId, parentAttributeValue, control);
        if (RecordCount > 0) {
            $("#budetails").val("0");
            $('#budetails').attr('disabled', false);
            $("#sbudetails").val("0");
            $('#sbudetails').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#sbu2details").val("0");
            $('#sbu2details').attr('disabled', true);
            $('.selectpickerdrop').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    }
    else {
        $("#budetails").val("0");
        $('#budetails').attr('disabled', true);
        $("#sbudetails").val("0");
        $('#sbudetails').attr('disabled', true);
        $("#sbu2details").val("0");
        $('#sbu2details').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.selectpickerdrop').selectpicker('refresh');
    }
});

$("#budetails").on('change', function () {
    parentAttributeValue = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
    if (parentAttributeValue != 0) {

        portfolioTypeId = 'NT_ID_004';
        control = $('#sbudetails');
        control.html('');
        GetHierarchyDetails(portfolioTypeId, parentAttributeValue, control);
        if (RecordCount > 0) {
            $("#sbudetails").val("0");
            $('#sbudetails').attr('disabled', false);
            $("#sbu2details").val("0");
            $('#sbu2details').attr('disabled', true);
            $('.selectpickerdrop').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    }
    else {
        $("#sbudetails").val("0");
        $('#sbudetails').attr('disabled', true);
        $("#sbu2details").val("0");
        $('#sbu2details').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.selectpickerdrop').selectpicker('refresh');
    }
});

$("#sbudetails").on('change', function () {
    parentAttributeValue = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
    if (parentAttributeValue != 0) {

        portfolioTypeId = 'NT_ID_017';
        control = $('#sbu2details');
        control.html('');
        GetHierarchyDetails(portfolioTypeId, parentAttributeValue, control);
        if (RecordCount > 0) {
            $("#sbu2details").val("0");
            $('#sbu2details').attr('disabled', false);
            $('.selectpickerdrop').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    }
    else {
        $("#sbu2details").val("0");
        $('#sbu2details').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.selectpickerdrop').selectpicker('refresh');
    }
});
```

// ajax call function

```
function GetHierarchyDetails(portfolioTypeId, parentAttributeValue, control) {
//$('.tooltip-inner').remove();
//$('.tooltip-arrow').remove();
RecordCount = 0;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "../../UserInterfaceV2/AL/Transaction.asmx/GetHierarchyDetails",
    data: JSON.stringify({ portfolioTypeId: portfolioTypeId, parentAttributeValue: parentAttributeValue }),
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        //GetToolTip();            
        data = $.parseJSON(data.d);
        if (data.length > 0) {
            control.empty();
            control.append($("<option></option>").val("0").html("Select"));
            for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
                {
                    if (data[index].PortfolioId && data[index].PortfolioId != '' && data[index].PortfolioName && data[index].PortfolioName != ''
                        && data[index].PortfolioName != null && data[index].PortfolioId != null)
                    {
                        control.append($('<option title="' + data[index].PortfolioName + ' [' + data[index].PortfolioId + ']'
                            + '">'+'</option>').val(data[index].PortfolioId).html(data[index].PortfolioName
                            + ' [' + data[index].PortfolioId + ']'));
                        RecordCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
            
        };
        $('.selectpickerdrop').selectpicker('refresh');  
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Oops! Something went wrong, could you please try again!');
    }
});
```

}

// Bootstrap select tooltip enable

```
$('.selectpickerdrop').selectpicker({
    liveSearch: true
}).on('loaded.bs.select', function (e) {
    var $el = $(this);
    var $lis = $el.data('selectpicker').selectpicker.main.elements;

    $($lis).each(function (i) {

        var tooltip_title = $el.find('option').eq(i).attr('title');

        $(this).tooltip({
            'title': tooltip_title || '',
            'placement': 'top',
            //'selector': '.selectpicker',
            container: $(this)
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the dropdowns are populated via ajax, using the `loaded.bs.select` event  won't work, because when this event is triggered, the ajax request is not completed (or not yet started).

If you are already using `.selectpicker('refresh')`, we can take advantage of `refreshed.bs.select` event and attach the tooltips in the callback of this event:

```js
$('.selectpickerdrop').selectpicker({
    liveSearch: true
}).on('loaded.bs.select', function (e) {
  // append static tooltips
})
.on('refreshed.bs.select', function(e) {
  // append dynamic tooltips
});
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wskm4edz/

Comment: Thanks for your kind effort. Even if we use `shown.bs.select` works fine with Ajax. Discovered it on Friday.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Yeah, `shown.bs.select` works. But it is triggered very often - every time the drop-down menu was visible to the user - and in some cases the tooltips do not need to be updated.