# Show tooltip on hover over option in dropdown selector

Tags: php, jquery, html, dropdown

How can I show a tooltip while the user hovers over a specific option in a dropdown?

I have this code which prints out a dropdown question based on XML code which is supposed to show tooltips on some of the options in the dropdown selector:

```
function createDropdownQuestion($node, $name)
{
    print "<select class='form-control'name=\"$name\" id=\"$name\>";
    $i = 0; 
    foreach($node->childNodes as $option)
    {
        if(nodeIsValidOption($option))
        {
            if ($option->hasAttribute("tooltip"))
            {
                print "<option title='Show this tooltip' value=\"$i\">$option->nodeValue</option>";
            }
            else
            {
                print "<option value=\"$i\">$option->nodeValue</option>";
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    print "</select>";
}
```

Comment: well, [have your read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249591/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-on-an-html-option-tag) -- whoops! looks like, you don't do something wrong on the tooltip part, just make sure that it outputs `<option title="Show this tooltip"...`. so.. i ask the question.. what's wrong..? cause i tried with `<select><?php print "<option title='tooltip' value=\"yep\">nein</option>" ?></select>` in [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) it actually works...

Comment: Check out this existing [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249591/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-on-an-html-option-tag).

Comment: Apparently it was working with my initial code, but I it's a delay on about 2 seconds which I didn't notice. Seems to be a delay on most actions on the server, which is a another problem for me to solve. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Just so you aren't going down a rabbit hole, the tooltip delay isn't a server issue.  The delay in a title-based tooltip's appearance is dependent upon the browser you are using.  The only way to get it to appear quicker is implement something in javascript using `onmouseover` event.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads up. Although I have some delay when clicking the radio buttons as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use `title="TOOLTIP TITLE"`.

For e.g: `<option title="tooltip">test</option>`

```html
<select id="">
  <option title="test">test</option>
  <option title="test 123">test123</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Yes, I had the title attribute included in my code. I didn't notice the tooltip at first due to delay on the server, so I thought it didn't work. Not sure why there is such a huge delay tho.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="text-align:center;">

  
  <br/>
  <br/>
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried that before, but it doesn't work inside dropdown menus for options.