# Additional information in Select Form

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

is there a way to show additional information when you point with your cursor on option tag?

`<select>
<option>Name...</option>
</select>`

For example some small info-bar near cursor where would be written help info. Thanks

Comment: Does this help? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249591/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-on-an-html-option-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249591/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-on-an-html-option-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `title` attribute to the `option`.

FYI: the `title` attribute is a Global attribute - - it can be used on just about any visible element to cause a tooltip to appear when that element is hovered over. It also provides some additional accessibility to the element.

```html
<select>
  <option title="Hello">Hello</option>
  <option title="Goodbye">Goodbye</option>  
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution is the [`title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) attribute.

In the below example, when you focus the select input and hover over an option, the title is shown.

```html
<select>
  <option title="more information 1..." value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option title="more information 2..." value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option title="more information 3..." value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option title="more information 4..." value="4">Option 4</option>
 </select>
```